# Can you use Pivot table report filters as an OR statement rather than AND?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am trying to utilise Pivot tables to pull together a list of items where a certain value appears in either of 2 columns (in the attached photo this is "Staff 1" and "Staff 2" being allocated to a project). Unfortunately, the report filters are processed as an AND statement and so if both are set to the same value there is no return.

We would need these filters to process as an OR statement, and list all projects for which the person appears in either of the two columns.

[The summary tab, which should list all projects as described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BboUU.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a method to use "OR" within pivot table selections based on what you need to filter. Here's one method, where you could add another column to your data. This column (column D in my picture), will use the following formula:

```
    =IF(OR(B2=$H$1,C2=$H$1),"Show","Hide")
```

Basically, you'll create your filter in cell H1 (pick list for all your names, or, manually type). Then column D will see if Staff1 or Staff2 match that name.

Then create your pivot table and filter by "Show". The only problem with this solution is you need to remember to refresh your pivot table after you select a different name.

[image]

**EDIT**

If using this type of logic in column D, then you don't need a pivot table. Just create a table in columns A:D, then filter on D.